# Change First Last name format to Last Name, First name in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a sheet of 30k rows, i am trying to import the data form excel sheet to access so that it can be updated on SharePoint. What i want is to convert name column from this format "Joy Mason" to "Mason, Joy"

Comment: is it always, and I mean ALWAYS two names, one first AND one last?

Comment: Yes, no middle initials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only 2 names nothing like `Sue Anne Jones` or `Joe Van Kamp`

Then you can split on the space and flip the order:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,99) & ", " & LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott.